# PHP extension unable to load

Tags: php, curl

I want to enable MySQL and Curl extension. therefore I uncomment the lines for enabling there extension into php.ini.

Also added environment variables to PHP to C:\PHP and PHRC to C:\PHP

Copied the dlls to system32

When i am opening php.exe , I am seeing the following error : Even tried to runing the code. it is throwing me this error 
Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\test.php on line 7

C:\PHP>php.exe
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ôC:\PHP\extö\php_curl
.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ôC:\PHP\extö\php_mysq
l.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0

I am using windows 7 , apache 2.2 and php 5

Comment: have you restarted apache lately?

Comment: Does the file C:\PHP\extö\php_mysq l.dll' exist? or is your dll somewhere else?

Comment: yes I did ....................................

Comment: This process has not changed in PHP5, please tag correctly. http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.extension-dir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take in consideration more things, like:

- Locate any php.ini file on your system. If you have installed PHP using and installer than a ini file could be found in the installation folder as in the Windows folder as well.
- Copy the libraries in the same folder with the php.exe extension.
- Check your configuration for those special characters you got going there. What is that character before C:\ and what is with that spacing in the filename?

  ôC:\PHP\extö\php_mysq l.dll

Comment: Yes there was a spacing issue , I have fixed that but still no luck.
I am thinking of uninstalling everything, and reinsatlling again. Is any installer whihc can configure php , IDE , my sql and apache. 

my goal is to use Curl api using php

Comment: The WAMP package will install the Apache, PHP, MySQL stack on Windows, and it's setup properly so you only have to uncomment curl there and restart Apache.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with a wrong dll file. 
You need a dll that is compatible with your php version.
Go to http://php.net and download new php package.

Or it can be a problem with a wrong value of "extension_dir" in php.ini
Try to change your extension directory to something simpler (without special characters), for example:
extension_dir = "c:/PHP/ext"